# ocaml immutable string advantage

Tags: ocaml, immutability

I recently encountered the `Astring` module for Ocaml at https://github.com/dbuenzli/astring.

The author of the library states the following in the readme:

```
...fully exploits OCaml's newfound string immutability
```

What sort of advantages does the immutability of strings bring to the implementation of a string library? I tried reading the source, but couldn't find any concrete advantages. Is there performance benefit?
Does it allow safer patterns?

Answer (score 4):

The main use of immutability is that you can manipulate substrings without requiring a copy of it.

This is why there is [a separate module for substrings](http://erratique.ch/software/astring/doc/Astring.String.Sub.html). This whole module would not be sound if strings were mutable.

Comment: Great! Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

When your function returns a string and that this string already exists as such you don't have to make a copy of that existing string for your result.

Here are a few simple examples:

```
String.append s "" 
String.append "" s
String.trim "bla"
```

If your strings are mutable you always have to return a copy in these cases.